# How to install Touchegg-GCE?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

please, help me!
how to install Touchegg-GCE in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev
```

Download the .zip file from [here](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce/)

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip Touchegg-gce-master.zip
cd Touchegg-gce-master
qmake
make && sudo make install
```

To launch `touchegg-gce` you have to go to that particular folder.

The binary is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, check your PATH. Or start via your Application Launcher, there is a `desktop` file in `/usr/local/share/applications/touchegg-gce.desktop`

[image]

Comment: @AmirQasemnezhadMoqadam If this users answer helped you, please click the check mark on the left of the answer, so others can easily find this information.

Comment: @AmirQasemnezhadMoqadam: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant to [the first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/682868) with some (small) advantages:

- it provides the code in a git repository, which is nice in case you consider working on it
- it provides the installed software in a Debian package, which makes uninstalling it clean and simple with `sudo apt remove touchegg-gce`

The instructions are as follows:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential libqt4-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev checkinstall

git clone https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce.git
cd Touchegg-gce
qmake && make
sudo checkinstall \
    --pkgname touchegg-gce \
    --pkgversion 1.3.1 \
    --pkgsource "https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce" \
    --provides touchegg-gce \
    make install
```

At this stage, this is only a very basic Debian / Ubuntu package. For example, it does not list any dependency packages, and it installs files into `/usr/local/` which is [not the proper way](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian#A.27.27Debianization.27.27). However, as a way to keep my local installation tidy an be able to uninstall things without having to research how exactly, I really like `checkinstall`.