# Right click on the touch screen doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

On the device is installed through [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) only linux-generic kernel, and some restricted modules, following the steps from [Installation/LowMemorySystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) with Fluxbox window manager the only installed environment.

The right click and the mouse for the touch screen are working normally.
Tell me please is there any way to enable right click on the touch screen?

Best regards.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346210/how-to-emulate-a-right-mouse-button-click-on-touchscreen - questions with bounties cannot be flagged as dupes, so just take a look at that link

Comment: Thank you Lynob `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse secondary-click-enabled "true"` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Easystroke allows gesture-based actions. You can configure it so when you, say, draw a circle, it right-clicks. I find it to work well.

To install it, go to Ubuntu Software and type 'easystroke' into the search bar. You can install it from there.

Comment: Thank you Merlin04, I've been trying easystroke, going to Preferences - Additional Buttons - Gesture Button - Click & Hold + Additional Buttons select Button 3, but still doesn't work I would like to keep the screen touched continuously for right click to work, if it will really not be possible, I will try to figure out at least how to use the gestures. If you don't have any clues for keep the touch screen pressed, tell me please the steps for gestures. Thank you.

Comment: First, click Actions. Then, click Add Action. Call it "Right Button". Then, click where it says "Command" and change it to "Button". A window will pop up. Right click in the gray area. Finally, click Record Stroke and draw the gesture on screen that you want to use. Then, you can draw the gesture on screen, and the next tap you make will be right click.

Comment: After "Record Stroke" it pop up the window Record a new stroke, the next stroke will be associated with the action "right button". You can draw it anywhere on the screen (except for two buttons below). I've tried making a circle from the wireless touch pad synaptics, keeping the left click pressed, pop up appears saying "You are about to bind an action to a single click. This might make it difficult to use Button 1 in the future. Continue?" clicking on yes left click will be used as right click, without having any more left click at all.

Comment: Are you drawing something or just clicking?

Comment: Tried to make a circle, a X, a square, in different parts of the scree, the pop up with "You are about to bind an action to a single click. This might make it difficult to use Button 1 in the future. Continue?" doesn't apear so fast, after more tries of drawing different things, in different parts of the screen. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any windows open? Try drawing the shape on your desktop instead of on top of a window.

Comment: I appreciate Merlin04, I have just resolved the right click with the help of onboard, more than keyboard, it also has the mouse option for right click like a real the mouse point, it works for touch screen directly just clicking wherever you want on the screen, and having the same effect like a left click of a mouse. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [Linux Kernel after 4.8.6](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/5cn0ku/1604_lts_on_hp_spectre_x360_kaby_lake_works_great) has nice touch integration added for touchscreens. Of course, your hardware is probably different from the three types mentioned in this answer. I recently booted the [Nov. 20 release of Antergos](https://antergos.com/try-it) on my [Dell Inspiron i5378-2885GRY 13.3" FHD 2-in-1 Laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L8PDMO6). There were a lot of features available that were not there with the 4.4 kernel in 16.04. On the kernel version of the Antergos live USB (It was above 4.8.6. Not sure exactly which version it was.), onscreen scrolling works, zoom in/out works, right clicking, and probably other features I am not aware of yet. When I booted the 16.10 iso with the 4.8.0 kernel more features were available compared to a 16.04 kernel version. It seems the [4.8.0 kernel added support for the Surface 3](https://fossbytes.com/linux-kernel-4-8-microsoft-surface-3-support/).  However, using the 4.8.6+ kernel has added the most functionality for me.

How to get the latest kernel is beyond the scope of this answer. You can try installing the 16.10 kernel (probably with partially better results). You could compile the kernel from source. You could use Arch or an Arch based distribution. I however, will plan to install Debian testing Gnome on the new laptop.