# How can I use multitouch gestures under LXQt with a touchscreen?

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen, multi-touch, lxqt

There is no global recognition of touchscreen multi-touch gestures in LXQt. This is unlike in the default Ubuntu Shell desktop environment, where for example a long-press touch event on the touchscreen triggers a right-click.

Multi-touch input events are however provided by the X server, and programs which have their own implementation of multi-touch gestures can be controlled with these gestures. For example, two-finger pinch zoom works in  Chrome / Chromium and [Evince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince).

But is there a way to have a global recognition of multi-touch gestures to perform certain configurable actions, such as "trigger right click" or "switch virtual desktop"?

What I tried: I know that the `xf86-input-wacom` driver has some (limited) gesture recognition including "tap-hold plus tap" for right-clicks. But I had to disable this as otherwise not even left-clicks would work on the touchscreen with some programs ([background story](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140063)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`touchegg`](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg).

### Installation and configuration

See [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140787).

### My experience with `touchegg`

Sadly, at least with my touchscreen (ThinkPad X201 Tablet), I have found that the more complex gestures like "two-finger pinch" are not recognized reliably enough by `touchegg`. With a bit of caution, it can be well used for two-finger-tap right-clicking ([details](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140787)). The two-finger-drag gestures are also recognized well, but for me, none beyond these.

### Alternatives to `touchegg`

- There is `fusuma`, a Ruby based application made for gesture recognition on touchpads. It may also work on touchscreens; I did not try yet. For installation instructions, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184).
- There is `libinput-gestures`, and you can find [recommendations for it](https://askubuntu.com/a/837231). In my understanding, this is however specific to the `libinput` driver, which is used for most touchpads. Touchscreens will usually use the `wacom` driver instead. But, I did not try this – there might be a way to get it to work.